# qt6 cmake, not auto copy plugins to build folder

Tags: cmake, qt6

As title say, the qt6 can't auto copy plugins folder to build folder, so this error throws

```
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

And my CMakeLists.txt is:

```
project(qt6_plugin_auto_import_test)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
add_executable(qt6_plugin_auto_import_test main.cc)

target_link_libraries(qt6_plugin_auto_import_test PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets)
```

And if I repalce Qt6 with Qt5, every thing ok.

After I did some reading the qt5 source. I thing the maybe the reason is Qt5Gui_QWindowsIntergationPlguins.cmake file:

```
add_library(Qt5::QWindowsIntegrationPlugin MODULE IMPORTED)


if(EXISTS "${_qt5Gui_install_prefix}/plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll")
    _populate_Gui_plugin_properties(QWindowsIntegrationPlugin RELEASE "platforms/qwindows.dll" FALSE)
endif()
if(EXISTS "${_qt5Gui_install_prefix}/debug/plugins/platforms/qwindowsd.dll")
    _populate_Gui_plugin_properties(QWindowsIntegrationPlugin DEBUG "platforms/qwindowsd.dll" FALSE)
endif()

list(APPEND Qt5Gui_PLUGINS Qt5::QWindowsIntegrationPlugin)
set_property(TARGET Qt5::Gui APPEND PROPERTY QT_ALL_PLUGINS_platforms Qt5::QWindowsIntegrationPlugin)
set_property(TARGET Qt5::QWindowsIntegrationPlugin PROPERTY QT_PLUGIN_TYPE "platforms")
set_property(TARGET Qt5::QWindowsIntegrationPlugin PROPERTY QT_PLUGIN_EXTENDS "-")
set_property(TARGET Qt5::QWindowsIntegrationPlugin PROPERTY QT_PLUGIN_CLASS_NAME "QWindowsIntegrationPlugin")
```

Which is remove in qt6.

Maybe I need manually write plugins copy script?